# WP Admin Bar frontend issue with dashicon deregister

Tags: hooks, actions, front-end, dashboard, admin-bar

A few days back I started working on re-optimizing my site to even great extent. While analyzing, I saw that WordPress dashicon files gets added to each page of my site but as we all use `fontawesome` now it is nothing but a waste.

So, I put the following code inside my `functions.php` file to deregister the dashicon files from the front end of my sites:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', function() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );
}, 100);
```

Now after adding this into my site, everything seems working fine but when I enabled the admin toolbar to be shown on the frontend of the site, I saw that the toolbar is not showing properly and it is broken.

So, again after analyzing the problem I saw that this is happening due to the deregister of dashicons.

Now my question is why the front end admin toolbar is broken up as soon as I deregister dashicons? Is is because the way I'm doing it or something else?

Any explanation will be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the [dashicons](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/) are used in the admin bar, so if you deregister them, your admin bar is broken. The easy way out is only to deregister the icons if there [is no admin bar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin_bar_showing):

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', function() {
    if (!is_admin_bar_showing()) wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );
}, 100);
```